make4ht and xymatrix in 2024
I am having trouble converting diagrams make using xymatrix using make4ht. In a discussion from 3 years ago, the following MWE and command line were said to work, but they do not. In light of the DoJ ruling that will be affecting many of us at public universities, I think this is a question lots of people are going to be searching for, so it would be good to have an updated discussion about it.
The MWE is here:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
$$
\xymatrix{
F(x) \ar[r]^{t_x} \ar[d]_{F(\phi)} & G(x) \ar[d]^{G(\phi)} \\
F(y) \ar[r]^{t_y} & G(y) }
$$
\end{document}

I am using the command line `make4ht sample.tex "svg,mathm,mathjax". The HTML output I get does not include an SVG file of the figure; rather, it contains the code, in red and yellow, indicating an error.
Has something changed in make4ht? Is there another way to do this in 2024? Thank you.

I think you want to use "mathml,mathjax,svg" options. You are missing l at the end of mathm. With your current options, you are asking TeX4ht to keep all math commands verbatim in the HTML output. Because MathJax doesn't know about \xymatrix, it will display your math as an error:

With correct "mathml" option, you will get this output:

It looks OK, the only problem is that it is enclosed in unnecessary MathML code:
<math display='block' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><mrow>
                       <img alt=' F (x)--tx--//G (x )
   |         |
F(ϕ)|         |G(ϕ)
     F (y)--ty--//G (y)' src='sample0x.svg' />
</mrow></math>

I would suggest to use a special environment that will work fine in the PDF output, but which would convert all its contents to picture. This way, it will work in both MathML and MathJax outputs.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\newenvironment{xycontainer}{$$}{$$}
\begin{document}
$$
\xymatrix{
F(x) \ar[r]^{t_x} \ar[d]_{F(\phi)} & G(x) \ar[d]^{G(\phi)} \\
F(y) \ar[r]^{t_y} & G(y) }
$$

Now in container:

\begin{xycontainer}
\xymatrix{
F(x) \ar[r]^{t_x} \ar[d]_{F(\phi)} & G(x) \ar[d]^{G(\phi)} \\
F(y) \ar[r]^{t_y} & G(y) }
\end{xycontainer}

\end{document}

See the xycontainer environment. We can redefine it in a TeX4ht config file:
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ConfigureEnv{xycontainer}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="xymatrix">}\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
\Css{.xymatrix{text-align: center;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble

It configures the xycontainer environment to be enclosed in a <div> element that can be styled using CSS to be centered, and to convert all environment contents to image using the \Picture*{} ... \EndPicture command.
When compiled with:
$ make4ht -c hej.cfg -lm draft -a debug sample.tex "svg,mathjax"

It produces the following output:

For MathML, compile using:
$ make4ht -c hej.cfg -lm draft -a debug sample.tex "svg,mathjax,mathml"

This is the result:


Thanks. This is great. A question, however: when I add the mathml option, all my macros (which I store in a separate file, and include as a package) appear in plaintext at the top of the converted files. Do you know how to get around this?

@Skeptic that sounds weird. In the LaTeX MathJax mode, you have an option to include LaTeX macros at the beginning of the document, so MathJax can recognize them. This is however hidden from the rendered output. Maybe you have \Configure{MathJaxMacros} somewhere in your config file? It this isn't the source of this issue, could you make a MWE and post it as a new question?
